# how to compare 2 datetimepicker vb.net

Tags: vb.net, date, compare

I'd like to compare 2 DateTimePicker's value

```
Dim dd1 As Date, dd2 As Date
Dim diff As Integer

dd1 = DateTimePicker1.Value
dd2 = DateTimePicker2.Value

diff = DateDiff("d", dd1, dd2)
If diff > 0 Then
  MsgBox("datetimpicker1datetimepicker2")
End If
```

but it doesn't work could  you help me please

Comment: What do you mean by saying doesn't work?

Comment: Keep in mind that DateDiff will return a negative number if the first date is later than the second date, which means your MsgBox will not be shown.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to compare would be to use the DateTime.Compare function.  For a simple "Are they the same?" you could try:

```
If Not DateTime.Compare(dd1,dd2) = 0 then
  'they are diffent
End If
```

Or if you want to be more specific then you might go with something like this:

```
If Not DateTime.Compare(dd1,dd2) = 0 then
  'they are same
ElseIf DateTime.Compare(dd1,dd2) > 0 then
  'dd1 is later than dd2
Else
  'dd1 is prior to dd2
End If
```

You can see more about DateTime.Comare here on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If You are using [DateDiff()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.90).aspx) then there are three case can be possible:-

1) DatePicker1 date is bigger than DatePicker2

2) DatePicker1 date is lower than DatePicker2

3) DatePicker1 date is equal to DatePicker2

To handle this, You have to use this

```
diff = DateDiff("d", dd1, dd2)
If diff > 0 Then
    MsgBox("datetimpicker1 is greater than datetimepicker2")
Else If diff < 0 Then 
    MsgBox("datetimpicker1 is lesser than datetimepicker2")
Else
    MsgBox("datetimpicker1 is equal to datetimepicker2")
End If
```